# ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I used the parse_dates and made the date column as the index of the dataframe

> To use "DF.asfreq('W')" to get the data Monthly.

I had this Error :

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 x1.asfreq('M')

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _can_reindex(self, indexer)
   3360         # trying to reindex on an axis with duplicates
   3361         if not self.is_unique and len(indexer):
-> 3362             raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
   3363 
   3364     def reindex(self, target, method=None, level=None, limit=None, tolerance=None):

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: The error is telling you that you have multiple rows that share the same index for the same day. `asfreq` doesn't know which one to pick so it instead complains. You either need to figure out how to deal with, or aggregate, the duplicates or if you want some haphazard way to handle it you'd do `df.resample('W').first()`. That picks the row that comes first.

Comment: Does it have any function like first()... to make count of the data with the same date

Comment: Resample is basically a groupby so all of that functionality is available. Try .size()